# Using Nested IF Statements to Import

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a few issues with the following code. I have had the main block running quite nicely, however, when I added the extra if statements I am now getting an excel hang. I know this is something to do with my if statements but i am not quite versed enough to work out what I have done.
Any help much appreciated.

```
Sub Import()
' Prevent screen from updating & define "directory" and "Filename"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CalculateFull
directory = "T:\JLR Project 2013\Joint Data\CHEATSHEETS\"
Filename = (directory & Cells(10, 16))

' Define Object for Target Workbook
Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Target_Path As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim myPassword As String
myPassword = Password1.Password.Value
' ------- REMOVE PASSWORD -------

' Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
' Change path of the Target File name
Target_Path = Filename
Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
' Unprotect the sheet so as to remove information
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Unprotect Password:=myPassword
Next sh
Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook
' Cheatsheet Rev 10
If Range("A22") = "Input" Then
    ' Select Force from sheet and copy
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c22")
    ' Paste Force into the big sheet
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h19") = Target_Data
    ' Select Head Height DTI
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("e17:e21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c33:c37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Head Height Macro
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("g17:g21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("d33:d37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Interlock
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("i17:j21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("e33:f37") = Target_Data
    ' Select T-Min
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("m17:m21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h33:h37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Parameters, cracks through etc
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("o17:s21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c49:g53") = Target_Data
Else

' Cheatsheet Rev 9
If Range("C15") = "Peak Force" Then
    ' Select Force from sheet and copy
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("C25")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h19") = Target_Data
    ' Select Head Height DTI
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("e17:e21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c33:c37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Head Height Macro
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("g17:g21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("d33:d37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Interlock
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("i17:j21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("e33:f37") = Target_Data
    ' Select T-Min
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("m17:m21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h33:h37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Parameters, cracks through etc
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("o17:s21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c49:g53") = Target_Data
Else

' Cheatsheet Rev 6
If Range("M15") = "Peak Force" Then
    ' Select Force from sheet and copy
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("M23")
    ' Paste Force into the big sheet
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h19") = Target_Data
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("C17:C21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c33:c37") = Target_Data
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("E17:E21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("d33:d37") = Target_Data
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("G17:H21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("e33:f37") = Target_Data
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("K17:K21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h33:h37") = Target_Data
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("N17:R21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c49:g53") = Target_Data
Else

' Cheatsheet Rev 4
If Range("M15") = "Cracks Through to Rivet?" Then
    ' Select Force from sheet and copy
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h19") = "--"
    ' Select Head Height DTI
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("C17:C21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c33:c37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Head Height Macro
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("E17:E21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("d33:d37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Interlock
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("G17:H21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("e33:f37") = Target_Data
    ' Select T-Min
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("K17:K21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h33:h37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Parameters, cracks through etc
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("M17:Q21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c49:g53") = Target_Data
Else

' Cheatsheet Rev 2
If Range("M15") = "" Then
    ' Select Force from sheet and copy
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h19") = "--"
    ' Select Head Height DTI
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("C17:C21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c33:c37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Head Height Macro
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("E17:E21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("d33:d37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Interlock
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("G17:H21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("e33:f37") = Target_Data
    ' Select T-Min
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("K17:K21")
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("h33:h37") = Target_Data
    ' Select Parameters, cracks through etc
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("c49:g53") = "--"
Else
MsgBox "ERROR FILE NOT SUPPORTED"

' Re-protect the workbook
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Protect Password:=myPassword
Next sh
' Save any changes in the two workbooks
Source_Workbook.Save
Target_Workbook.Save
Target_Workbook.Close False

' Re-calculate all of the sheets within the targate workbook to allow images to be imported
Application.CalculateFull

Image

' Process Completed
MsgBox "Import Complete"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You opened 5 *If* clauses and closed only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to Rubik's perfectly acceptable method:

```
If Range("A22") = "Input" Then
  'stuff
Else
  If Range("C15") = "Peak Force" Then
    'stuff
  Else
    If Range("M15") = "Peak Force" Then
      'stuff
    Else
      If Range("M15") = "Cracks Through to Rivet?" Then
        'stuff
      Else
        If Range("M15") = "" Then
          'stuff
        Else
          MsgBox "ERROR FILE NOT SUPPORTED"
'This is the critical difference to your code:
        End if
      End if
    End if
  End if
End if
' Re-protect the workbook
'and the rest of your code here - be sure to get rid of the now random
'End If that would be down there
```

If you were to just add all the `End If`s to where you've got the one now, you'd find that you would only re-protect the worksheet & save your changes *if* you first saw your `ERROR FILE NOT SUPPORTED` message.

Comment: Please be sure to accept whichever answer you felt was most helpful. Having accepted answers helps the whole site.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you've got:

```
Else

' Cheatsheet Rev 9
If Range("C15") = "Peak Force" Then
```

Try to replace `Else ... If` by `ElseIf` (in one word):

```
...
' Cheatsheet Rev 9
ElseIf Range("C15") = "Peak Force" Then
...
```

But I can't tell where you have to put your `End If` instruction...

Comment: I would put the `End If` after the `Else
MsgBox "ERROR FILE NOT SUPPORTED"`